# Python type error: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm defining a set of functions to convert from an Earth-centered reference frame to classical orbital elements. Here are my codes:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#converting r,v to orbital elements
u = 3.986*10e14 #gravitational parameter for Earth
list_r = [-2413.9, 6083.8, -1136.0]
r = np.array(list_r)
list_v= [-6.5461, -3.1365, -3.6385] 
v = np.array(list_v)

def h(r,v):
    return np.cross(r,v)


list_k = [0,0,1]
k = np.array(list)

def n(k,h):
    return np.cross(k,h)
def e_vec(v,r):
    vector = 1/u * (np.dot((np.linalg.norm(v))**2-u/np.linalg.norm(r),r)-np.dot(np.dot(r,v),v))
    return vector

def p(h,u):
    return (np.linalg.norm(h))**2/u
        

def a(p,e):
    return p/(1-np.linalg.norm(e_vec)**2)



def i(h):
    
    return np.arccos(np.dot(k,h(r,v))/np.linalg.norm(h(r,v)))
   

list_I = [1,0,0]
I = np.array(list_I)

def ohm(I,n):

    nI = np.dot(n(h),I)
    ohm = np.acos(nI/n)
    return ohm
    
def w(n,e):
    w = np.arccos(np.dot(n,e)/(np.linalg.norm(n)*np.linalg.norm(e)))
    return w

def f(e,r):
    f = np.arccos(np.dot(e_vec(v,r),r)/(np.linalg.norm(e_vec(v,r))*np.linalg.norm(r)))
    return f
print(h(r,v))
print(e_vec(v,r))
print(p(h(r,v),u))
print(i(h(r,v)))
print(ohm(I,n))
print(w)
print(f)
```

I'm getting this error : TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable, for the function i(h). I don't know how I should fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you're getting confused by scoping.

`h(r, v)` is the *result* of a function, and thus a `numpy` array - while `h` is the function itself.  You're passing `h(r, v)` to `i` as `h`, but still expecting `h` in scope `i` to be a function.

Also `k` isn't in scope for `i`, so that will also cause an error.  you should probabaly define

```
def i(k, r, v): 
    return np.arccos(np.dot(k, h(r, v)) / np.linalg.norm(h(r, v)))
```

and pass `i(k, r, v)`, or define:

```
def i(k, h): 
    return np.arccos(np.dot(k, h) / np.linalg.norm(h))
```

and pass `i(k, h(r, v))`

An even better method would be to wrap it all in a `class` and keep all your variables in a `self` scope so that it's easier to keep track, but the frontend work of object-oriented programming may be a step beyond what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have a function named `def h(r,v)` and you also name the argument as `h`. This is a conflict. In the function `i`'s scope, name `h` refers to the argument, that is, an numpy.ndarray, not the function. You should avoid using the same name.

Comment: I am intending to use the function h as the input of function i. How should I change the variable names?

Comment: @ArnoldSchwarzenegger I think you should name your variable more properly. When I read your code, I have no idea what's going on because I can't understand what's each variable and each function means. e.g. `h`, `i`, `n`, they are not suitable for function names. I suggest you making your code more clear then I can help you debug your code. I recommend you learn naming convention first. regards.

Comment: It's not a problem with function names, it's a problem with scoping.

Answer (score 1):

While local variables can be short, single names, functions should be more informative.  In particular you have defined a function `h`, but you also use `h` as a local variable.  That confuses you (and us).

In several of the functions `h` is a local variable, and an array (at least that's that `np.cross` expects):

```
def n(k,h):
    return np.cross(k,h)
```

Similarly for

```
def p(h,u):
    return (np.linalg.norm(h))**2/u
```

But `i` breaks that pattern:

```
def i(h):
    return np.arccos(np.dot(k,h(r,v))/np.linalg.norm(h(r,v)))
```

Here `h` only works if it is a function.  But you haven't passed in `r`, `v` or `k`.

```
def i(k,h):
    return np.arccos(np.dot(k,h)/np.linalg.norm(h)
```

is more consistent with your other functions.  It is also more consistent with

```
print(i(h(r,v)))
```